# List with a Struct in C++

Tags: c++, list, struct, linked-list

I have a "Squadron" class which has several "Ships" in a list. This is an exercise and I'm not allowed to use STL containers.

The aim is to keep things as simple as possible and therefore not to implement a complicated class (like a complete LinkedList class), which is why I've gone for the idea of a "struct" with pointers to "node" and "next".

However, I don't really know how to go about it, so I started with an idea like this:

```
 struct ShipNode {
 Ship* node
 Ship* next

Constructor
Destructor
}

struct ShipListNode {
 Ship* head
     
Constructor
Destructor

AddShip
RemoveShip
}
```

Does this sound like a good idea or do you have any others? And does my initial implementation seem logical?

I'm also wondering how I'm going to manage the nodes in my list. I think I'd need a pointer to an iterator in "ShipListNode", don't you think? As for "head", I wonder if it shouldn't be static. Since I have a list by Squadron class only, that wouldn't be a problem or would it?

Thanks to anyone who takes the time to reply, and have a nice day!

Comment: "not to implement a complicated class" and "not allowed to use STL containers" are mutually exclusive. If you have to manage your own memory, your code will be either very complex or plain wrong.

Comment: this sounds like you need to learn about the rule of 3/5

Comment: why is the `node` member a pointer?

Comment: if they ask you to implement a linked list from scratch, they must have told you how to do that. At least the rough idea should have been discussed in the lecture. Letting beginners guess how this works is the opposite of teaching. There is just too much to go horribly wrong if you dont know what is necessary to get it right

Comment: `ShipListNode` looks like it cannot decide whether it wants to be a list or one node in the list

Comment: "Is it a good idea" is a way to broad question for this site. In principle trying to implement your own container, or managing the memory by hand, is a bad idea. For some reasons they keep teaching C++ in this way in the universities.

Comment: If your class is a datastructures class, make a small reusable list class of your own. (And test it in isolation). If you are attending a C++ class, then ask your teacher to stop teaching "C" and start teaching "C++" and use std::list anyway. Show him this in any case : [Stop teaching "C"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk).

Comment: Oh and also tell your teacher to read these : [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines). I would even be tempted to help him (her?) update the course material.

Comment: *...not allowed to use STL containers...*  Don't use STL containers.  Instead use Standard C++ Library containers.  STL hasn't been maintained since about 1994, and probably doesn't work well with modern C++ compilers.

Comment: *The aim is to keep things as simple as possible and therefore not to implement a complicated class* -- You can't implement something "simple" and at the same time expect to do simple things to get this implemented.  It doesn't work that way.   For this, you have to write low-level code that manages pointers, dynamically allocated memory, and other aspects (like the rule of 3) -- otherwise what you have is code that *may* "work", but is actually a pile of junk with all sorts of issues that you may not know about.

Comment: This will be a "complete" linked list by the time you're done with it. Everything you need is explained in detail in any description of how to implement a linked list.

Comment: `struct` is not "simpler" than `class`. Both keywords denote class types, they only differ in default access; public and private respectively